# How to resize image without losing quality

Tags: c#, .net, image, graphics

Hey I have this Image:

[image]

i am using this method to resize my images:

```
public static Bitmap ResizeImage(Image image, int width, int height)
{
    var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    var destImage = new Bitmap(width, height);

    destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
    {
        graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
        graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

        using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
        {
            wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
            graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
        }
    }

    return destImage;
}
```

However when I'm done this would be my result:

[image]

As You can see the picture is somehow dotty and poor quality. So changed my approach and used this Method to resize my picture:

```
public static Image ResizeImage(Image OriginalImage, Size ThumbSize)
{
    Int32 thWidth = ThumbSize.Width;
    Int32 thHeight = ThumbSize.Height;
    Image i = OriginalImage;
    Int32 w = i.Width;
    Int32 h = i.Height;
    Int32 th = thWidth;
    Int32 tw = thWidth;
    if (h > w)
    {
        Double ratio = (Double)w / (Double)h;
        th = thHeight < h ? thHeight : h;
        tw = thWidth < w ? (Int32)(ratio * thWidth) : w;
    }
    else
    {
        Double ratio = (Double)h / (Double)w;
        th = thHeight < h ? (Int32)(ratio * thHeight) : h;
        tw = thWidth < w ? thWidth : w;
    }
    Bitmap target = new Bitmap(tw, th);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target);
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, tw, th);
    g.DrawImage(i, rect, 0, 0, w, h, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    return (Image)target;
}
```

But The Issue still stands. i was wondering how may i be able to resize this image to smaller size without losing quality.

I must add After resize i will create an byte array and save it within the database (Yes i know bad thing, but within this project it has to be saved within database). Also on retrieval I get the image from webapi, so that byte array will be converted to base64 string. and i show that b64 on image tag like below. e.g:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
    9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="/>
```

Comment: the image looks like vector gfx so in case you got the original vector form just render it with your desired resolution. That will be without any loss (unless too small resolution is used) of quality. Any raster gfx resizers will lose quality no matter what you do (unless multiple of original resolution is used). Your image has a bit noise in it maybe smoothing it before down size will help improve result. The result is looking like it is using dithering arent you converting also color bitwidth from `15/16/24/32bit -> 8bit` ?

Comment: @Spektre no i am not convering its color bitwidth to 8bit.. there has to be something creating this issue here, could it because i send it to database or showing the image as base64 on img tag? checking atm..

Comment: This is not my cup of tea but I imagine that **DBS** engine could "optimize" your image to 8bit on its own to preserve space

Comment: @Spektre alright let me track the rest from here.

Comment: try nearest neighbor resizing filter ... if the dots are present even there then it is most likely dithering somewhere. Also are you sure target image pixelformat matches the source image (not a C# user)?

Comment: I am not aware of the final use case and why you are resizing like this. But if resizing images via URL parameter is something which will make your life easy, please also check out ImageKit.io - https://imagekit.io.

Comment: `Bitmap` is a subclass of `Image`, so you don't really have to cast `target` back to `Image` in the `return` statement. I'm wondering how you convert the Image object to base64 png though.

Comment: This is the way you should ask a question.Simple and straight.Thank you @Valkyrie

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm using the following method for thousands of images and it never loses significant quality or results in a dotted image.

```
public static Image ScaleImage(Image image, int height)
{
    double ratio = (double)height/ image.Height;
    int newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
    int newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);
    Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
    {
        g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    }
    image.Dispose();
    return newImage;
}
```

I've taken the liberty of scaling the image you posted using this code to 128px (Like the thumbnail you posted).

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hey man i used your method, it is kinda the same as before... I'm starting to think there is another issue. could it because i use base64 string to show my image on img tag?

Comment: Why do you do that? After you rescale the image, why don't you just show it as it is?

Comment: The result has to be saved within database in the end. but i am checking this as well to see if the issue still present or not then i can track the rest from this point.

Comment: @ecKO OK, let me know if I can assist in any way.

Comment: Hey man i just made it work with your method and it works perfectly now. thank you my vote up for this answer.

Comment: @ecKO Happy to help! Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

This method have been working great for me.

Just create a new Size with the Width and Height that you want and create a new Bitmap using the image that you want to scale.

```
public Bitmap GetResizeImage(Bitmap bm, int newWidth, int newHeight)
{
    var newSize = new Size(newWidth, newHeight);

    return new Bitmap(bm, newSize);
}
```